# Weird Answer involving Minimum

Tags: calculus, geometry, word-problem

> Given the isosceles triangle $ABC$, in which $AB$ is 12 inches and the altitude $CD$ is 3 inches, find the point $P$ on CD such that the sum of the distances of P from the vertices is a minimum.

This problem seemed fairly simple.
Here's the equation that I set up:

$$2\sqrt{x^2+36} + 3 - x = d$$

Then, I took the derivative, set it to zero, and hoped to find the minimum:
$$2 \cdot 2x \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+36}} -1 = d'$$
$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+36}} = 1$$
$$4x^2 = x^2 + 36$$
$$x = 2\sqrt{3}$$

Firstly, my book says the answer should be where the point C lies (i.e, the length $x = 3$ inches). Secondly, $2\sqrt{3} > 3$.

If I'm right, I would like to know how to interpret this result (as I had obtained similar answers for previous questions). If I'm not right, I would like to know how I screwed up something so basic so I can then proceed to bash my head on the wall for the next few hours (not really).

Thanks.

Edit: Here's a better picture.

[image]

Comment: You should draw a figure and define your variables.  What are $x$ and $d$?   Which are the two sides of $ABC$ that are equal?  I can't tell whether your first equation is correct or not.

Comment: Can you say where your equation came from?  I can't follow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not explain how you derive your governing equation; things might have gone wrong somewhere there. Consider this:

If we make the point $A$ our origin of coordinates, then $B$ becomes $(12,0)$ and $C$ becomes $(m,3)$, where $0<m<12,$ indicates the length of $AD.$ The distances from our point $(m,y)$ from the three vertices is as follows: $$\begin{align}{|PA|=\sqrt{y^2+m^2}\\ |PB|=\sqrt{y^2+(m-12)^2}\\ |PC|=\sqrt{(y-3)^2}\\ }\end{align},$$ so that it is their sum that you want to minimize as $y$ varies in the bounds $[0,3].$

You should be able to continue from here?

Edit: When I took note of the fact that $|AC|=|CB|,$ so that consequently, $m=6,$ and simplified, differentiated and set to nullity, I got $$4y^2(y-3)^2=(3-y)^2(y^2+36).$$ It is now easy to see where OP lost his solution, since it is very tempting to cancel the equal factors; but recall that $3$ is in the domain of $y,$ so that we cannot legitimately cancel. Thus, letting $K=(3-y)^2,$ we get $$(4y^2-y^2-36)K=0,$$ from which we also get the possibility $y=3.$

Hope OP doesn't bang his head on a wall. :)

Comment: I've now uploaded a picture that will help understand how I derived the equation. I essentially set up the exact same equations as you, except that $m=6$ (since the length of $AD$ is half of $AB$)

Comment: @S.Sharma Oh, I did not even take note that $|AC|=|CB|.$ I have edited accordingly. See above.

Answer (score 2):

First observe that your function $d$ is a decreasing function of $x (\because$ its derivative is negative $\forall x\in[0,3])$.

Now, since we are restricted in this interval only, the required minimum occurs at $x=3$.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I think I understand why the answer is $x = 3$.
If my equation is correct, then what I've found is the *relative minimum* of the function. However, we must find the *absolute minimum*, i.e, the minimum of the function in between the interval [a, b] (in this case $a=0$ and $b=3$). Therefore, because $b < 2\sqrt{3}$, the solution within the interval [0, 3] is $x = 3$. This point was made by @Allawonder and @Martund

If my reasoning is incorrect, then I would love feedback.